# How to keep Quotes For Making proper SQL Query

Tags: java

When i run the below program

```
package com.util;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list_of_symbols = new ArrayList<String>();
        list_of_symbols.add("ABB");
        list_of_symbols.add("ACC");
        list_of_symbols.add("SBIN");
        StringBuilder sb_builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < list_of_symbols.size(); i++) {
            sb_builder.append(list_of_symbols.get(i) + ",");
        }
        String sql = "Select * from data where symbol_name IN ("
                + sb_builder.deleteCharAt(sb_builder.length() - 1).toString()
                + ")";
        System.out.println(sql);
    }
}
```

The Result of SQL IS

```
Select * from data where symbol_name IN (ABB,ACC,SBIN)
```

Where as the expected result should be

```
Select * from data where symbol_name IN ('ABB','ACC','SBIN')
```

Could you please let me know how can i keep Quotes so that it becomes valid SQL

Comment: just add `'` to your query string

Comment: You cant keep them, as they are not there. You have to add them.

Comment: offtopic: combining strings makes SQL injection possible, you should avoid this

Comment: Use prepared statements

Answer (score 6):

Don't use string concatenation to fill in SQL parameters. It's error-prone. Instead, build the SQL with as many `?` as you need, and then use a `PreparedStatement` and as many `setString(x, theString)` as you need to fill in the `?`.

In your case, it would look *roughly* like this:

```
package com.util;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list_of_symbols = new ArrayList<String>();
        list_of_symbols.add("ABB");
        list_of_symbols.add("ACC");
        list_of_symbols.add("SBIN");

        // Build the statement
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(200);
        sql.append("Select * from data where symbol_name IN (");
        for (int i = 0; i < list_of_symbols.size(); i++) {
            sql.append(i == 0 ? "?" : ", ?");
        }
        sql.append(')');

        // Build the PreparedStatement and fill in the parameters
        PreparedStatement ps = someConnection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < list_of_symbols.size(); i++) {
            ps.setString(i + 1, list_of_symbols.get(i));
        }

        // Do it
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    }
}
```

*(This is un-optimized, and dashed off. Some editing is likely required.)*

[This site](http://bobby-tables.com/) has a good explanation of why using string concat for parameters is a bad idea, as well as practical examples of how to do things properly in many languages, including [Java](http://bobby-tables.com/java.html).

Comment: A good reference for writing safe SQL [here (OWASP injection prevention cheatsheet)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @Jan: *"(This is un-optimized, and dashed off. Some editing is likely required.)"*

Answer (score 0):

As you *know* the number of values in your list I'd suggest to put in one ? per IN value and make it a PreparedStatement.

Then simply do

```
 ps.setString (n, nthString);
```

In a loop for 1..n parameters and your driver will handle proper escaping.

Like this:

```
    List<String> list_of_symbols = new ArrayList<String>();
    list_of_symbols.add("ABB");
    list_of_symbols.add("ACC");
    list_of_symbols.add("SBIN");
    StringJoiner join = new StringJoiner(",",
            "Select * from data where symbol_name IN (", ")");
    for (int i = 0; i < list_of_symbols.size(); i++) {
        join.add("?");
    }
    PreparedStatement ps = aConnection.prepareStatement(join.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < list_of_symbols.size(); i++) {
        ps.setString(i+1, list_of_symbols.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When making your list, use this:

```
sb_builder.append("'"+list_of_symbols.get(i) + "',");
```

Notice the `'` on the string. This works for simple cases only, where strings do not have `'` and you're not worried with SQL Injection. For more complex cases, used `PreparedStatements` and add a list of `?`. Then replace the `?` with the Strings you want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i was getting confused.

Comment: @PreethiJain: Of course, if there are `'` in your strings, this will fail. Concatenating parameters is *poor practice*, a habit it's best not to get into.

Comment: You answer is bad because your code is vulnerable the SQL Injection.

Comment: @TT.: Well, if you know you're not dealing with externally-sourced information (so, not user input, not reading a file, etc.), it would be *okay*. That's why I talked of habits. But if I have any option, I would use a PreparedStatement even with internally-source information. Just too easy to mess up otherwise. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Then we both follow the path of least resistance.